# object referencing/mongoose-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been taking colt Steeles's web development bootcamp classes,so i am on the associations topic. tried writing code to do a one to many association via object referencing, the code appears thus

```
var mongoose= require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blogApp_demo_2",{useNewUrlParser:true});
var postSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
     title:String,
     content:String
});

var post= mongoose.model("post",postSchema);

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    Email:String,
    posts:[
        {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"post"
    }]
});

var user= mongoose.model("user",userSchema);

post.create(
     {
     title:"beauty in the lilies",
     content: "there is so much to marvel in lilies"
 }, function(err,post){
     user.findOne({email:"deleomoarukhe@yahoo.com"}, function(err,foundUser){
         if(err){
             console.log(err);
             } else{
                 foundUser.posts.push(post);
                 foundUser.save(function(err,data){
                     if(err){
                         console.log(err);
                     }else{
                         console.log(data);

                     }
             });
        }
     });
});
```

but on trying to execute this code it gives me this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of null

tried everything i can to get this code running, to no avail.

p.s the code was to add a further comment to an already existing user.

Comment: key in the user schema is `Email` and you are trying to find by `email`.

Comment: The error means that `foundUser` is `null`. That's because nothing in the database matched the query conditions. `email:"deleomoarukhe@yahoo.com"` If you think there is a document that matches that, then show the document.

Comment: thanks, Shivam and Neil, apparently i didn't type the keyword "Email" correctly, I typed it as "email" instead.... made the correction and it came out just fine....many thanks guys